# how to link external js file in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

Went through other similar question on SO, but unable to fix my issue. I have written `src` path inside `script` tag.

Below is the program:

```js
    function validate()
    {
        var fname = document.myForm.fname.value;
        var lname = document.myForm.lname.value;
        
        if(fname=="" && lname=="")
        {
            alert("First and last name cannot be emtpy");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <script src="/js/validation.js"></script>
            <title>Registration Form</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
            First name:<input type="text" name="fname" /> <br/>
            Last name:<input type="text" name="lname" /><br/>
            Gender: Male<input type="radio" name="male" /> Female<input type="radio" name="male" /><br/>
            Mobile:<input type="tel" name="mobile" /><br/>
            Email:<input type="email" name="email" /><br/>
            Address:<textarea name="tarea"></textarea><br/>
            Street:<input type="text" name="street" /><br/>
            Area:<input type="text" name="area" /><br/>
            
            City:<select>
                <option value="hyderabad">hyderabad</option>
                <option value="secunderabad">secunderabad</option>
                <option value="delhi">delhi</option>
                <option value="mumbai">mumbai</option>
            </select>
    
            State: <input type="text" name="state" /><br/>
            Country: <input type="text" name="country" /><br/>
            Pin: <input type="text" name="pin" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

My js file is in the folder called js inside the webapp directory

Comment: Its working here through the snippet, but its not working in my browser(chrome). Its just forwarding the request to the servlet without validation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The below line fixed my problem:

```
<script src="<%request.getContextPath()%>/js/validation.js"></script>
```

Comment: not both the lines are needed.. and are your html pages contained in directory rather than directly root, if so then you need to use `src="../js/validation.js"`

Comment: @vinayakj Using a relative path means you'll always have to figure out where the JSP is, though; using an absolute path is almost always the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

The correct link is:

```
<script src="/js/validation.js"></script>
```

Note correct spelling of `src` attribute.

You could also include the request context, although the leading `/` should be sufficient under most circumstances.

Unrelated, but you should probably trim leading/trailing white space in your validation routine, and you spelled `empty` wrong.

Comment: @kittu That's why I said you might need the request context. Although you certainly don't need *both*; you'll make the same request twice.